# Gwt error ...No source code is available for type java.io.FileOutputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

currently i am using smartgwt to export csv file from list grid i am using fileoutput stream to write listgrid data into csv The problem is that it compiled successfuly but on the run time it gives * No source code is available for type java.io.FileOutputStream; did you 
forget to inherit a required module?*

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575909/gwt-did-you-forget-to-inherit-a-required-module/5576713#5576713

Answer (score 3):

GWT is a client-side library. There are no files on the client side. Therefore, FileOutputStream cannot compile into JavaScript.