# Java Timer in GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt, libgdx

I'm trying to have a Java Timer in my EntryPoint:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(
   new TimerTask() {
       public void run() {
           //some code
       }
   }
   , 5000);
```

But when trying to compile this I got:
No source code is available for type `java.util.Timer`; did you forget
to inherit a required module?

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT - did you forget to inherit a required module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575909/gwt-did-you-forget-to-inherit-a-required-module)

Comment: Not really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575909/gwt-did-you-forget-to-inherit-a-required-module because its in the context of Libgdx.  Though that link is definitely useful to explain where the error is originating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Libgdx, you can use [the libgdx `Timer` infrastructure](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html) to schedule work to run in the future:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleTask(new Timer.Task() { 
      public void run() { /* some code */ } 
  }), /* Note that libgdx uses float seconds, not integer milliseconds: */ 5);
```

This way you can schedule the timer in your platform independent code.  (The GWT-specific solution will only work in the platform dependent part of your project.)

Answer (score 14):

**In GWT you are restricted to use all the Util package classes.**

Here is the [List of Classes](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_util) only you can use from util class.

You can use [GWT Timer class](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html).

Example(*from docs*);

```
 public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // Create a new timer that calls Window.alert().
    Timer t = new Timer() {   //import (com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer)
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Window.alert("Nifty, eh?");
      }
    };

    // Schedule the timer to run once in 5 seconds.
    t.schedule(5000);
  }
```

Comment: Please always add latest documentation links.

Comment: Oops..didn't check.Sorry for the old link.Thanks for the edit @SSR.

Comment: Added comment besides new Timer() is very important. Generally people will choose java.util.Timer (Like me ;) ) Thanks!