# Gwt compiling error: unable to find type

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I have an error compiling my app:

```
[INFO] Compiling module com.messagedna.web.Main
[INFO]    Finding entry point classes
[INFO]       [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.messagedna.web.client.controller.Main'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
[INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

I've tryed to find the solution in google but didn't figured out any. 
here is my gwt.xml file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.6//EN"
        "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/releases/1.6/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>

    <inherits name='com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT'/>

    <inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.charts.Chart"/>

    <entry-point class='com.messagedna.web.client.controller.Main'/>

    <source path="com.messagedna"></source>


</module>
```

Comment: of course I have this class. Well, all necessary classes are in com.messagedna.web.client package. I use Idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source-path in your module XML file does not look right. The path should point to a package (directory name) relatively to the GWT module root. Since your GWT module root is `com.messagedna.web` and the default source path is `client`, you can just drop the source tag from your configuration.

Comment: This source tag is nesessary to point on one class which is out of the client package

Comment: but I already have noticed that it is not the good idea and moved that class to client package and now have another problem:`Validating newly compiled units
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/home/mikhail/bzrrep/DLP/DLPServer/src/main/java/com/messagedna/web/client/util/Config.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 8: The import java.util.concurrent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 9: The import java.util.concurrent cannot be resolved` and the same about  couldn't find main class. When I remove all imports of Config class everything compiles but not works

Comment: Are you striking this issue ?? Answer of mine : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528500/java-timer-in-gwt/15528569#

Comment: Yes you cannot use the class java.util.concurrent in GWT.

Comment: You can not use `java.util.concurrent` in GWT. Try to use the `Timer` and `DeferredCommand` mechanism. See [Programming Delayed Logic](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed).

Comment: @NikitinMikhail as Adrian said, you can check my question for example code

Comment: I used timer in my previous projects, put here the situation is differ. I have many customers which will access this app asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

You have the entry point class, but that it isn't compiled, because you have a compiler or a "linker" error, and that is why is nagging the last case as it is not entry point.

> [INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made
>   this type unavailable [INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Check the
>   inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a
>   required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries
>   properly

So check the other compiler errors or class-path included jars

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in module tag `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />`