# Port / Compile JAVA framework to Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, llvm

I'm currently working on a project for university. One of my profs developed a P2P Framework in JAVA. Now we have the task to get this running on different mobile devices. On Android this shouldn't be a big deal. But now it comes to iOs. I was thinking about the easiest way to port the framework. One way would be to port it completely to Objective-C but we don't have time for this. Then I thought about LLVM or GWT which can (in my very basic knowledge) compile JAVA to Javascript. So that we can run this inside a WebView or something like this. Until now I wasn't able to find a working LLVM frontend for JAVA. And I have no experiences with Google WebToolkit. Have some of you already experiences in this area? Is my plan a no go or is there a realistic way to solve this problem? Hope you can share some experiences, ideas or tips about this topic.

Felix

Comment: This might tell you the story.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528500/java-timer-in-gwt/15528569#15528569

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a no go. GWT compiles only JAVA subset to javascript. It does not map io, threads, sockets into web!!

GWT translates only the following java api subset to javascript - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation