# How to check if given string is of specific date format?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to check if a given string is in a particular dateformat. If not user should be able to throw error message.

```
DateTimeFormat format=DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");               
Date d= format.parse("1990-10-");
```

with this input , it should give error. I tried with try and catch , but its not throwing any exception.

Comment: Ofcourse, there's no way to know if for example `2013-08-12` is in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` (12 August 2013) or `yyyy-dd-MM` (8 December 2013).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the class

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/shared/DateTimeFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)

Which is in shared package.

Not the clinet package class

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

Use java.text.SimpleDateFormat, it throws ParseException.

```
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");               
try {
  Date d= format.parse("1990-10-");
} catch (ParseException e) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: No,GWT won't support it.

Comment: yup, GWT client side does not support it

Comment: I never worked with GWT, but really? It's standard Java class for crying out loud. Now I know, why some of my colegues bitch about GWT so much.

Comment: Please have a look [GWT wont convert all java classes] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528500/java-timer-in-gwt/15528569#15528569)

Comment: @RadekWroblewski I  understood.Your surprise revealed there :)  Anyway +1 for try catch block. Good day.

Comment: That's not GWT's point to implement the whole JVM in Javascript. Thus only a limited part of the Java standard libraries is available in the client.

Comment: And, no offence, but maybe you shouldn't answer GWT related questions if you have never worked with it :)

Comment: For classes in `java.text` to be handled correctly, there are megabytes of properties files that would need to be compiled in - in many cases it isn't possible to test if they will actually be used or not because they are parsed and used at runtime.